# Filtering nested data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I have a many to many relationship between Books and Categories and I want to filter the books by category. What I am missing here ? because it returns unfiltered books.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.bookService.getBooks()
  .subscribe(
  books => {
    this.filteredBooks = books.filter(
      book => book.categories.filter(cat => cat.categoryId === this.route.snapshot.params['categoryId']));

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.categoryId = params['categoryId'];
      this.updateList();
    });
  });
  }

updateList() {
    if (this.categoryId > 0) {
      this.books = this.filteredBooks;
    }
  }
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `this.route.snapshot.params['categoryId']` it could be undefined  try by follow this var befeore used

Comment: It's not undefined, I already checked. And even if I hardcode a number it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: OK, I think that I found the issue, look the post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using `find` in the second search

```
this.filteredBooks = books.filter(
      book => book.categories.find(
       cat => cat.categoryId === this.route.snapshot.params['categoryId']
      ) != undefined);
```

Comment: I edited the answer adding a conditional when you found a category return a `true` to filter function

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: could you share the structure of books object? or an example of you structure

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, this code is really bad and full of risk when u code like that.

First, you subscribe two time and it is not good since you have to       unsubscribe it later.

Second, `this.route.snapshot.params['categoryId']` it is hard to control the output.

Third, It is too hard to understand `this.categoryId = params['categoryId'];` and `this.route.snapshot.params['categoryId']`. It is like duplicated code, isn't it?

So My suggestion is that you can try to use **predictable state container** like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) in order to implement programs better.

Back to your problem I guess root cause from this method. Did you check that?

```
updateList() {
    if (this.categoryId > 0) { // maybe this is false ???
      this.books = this.filteredBooks;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this.categoryId = params['categoryId']; in order to be able to reload the page everytime I click on another category in the menu.

Comment: And even if I use only                                    
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.bookService.getBooks()
  .subscribe(
  books => {
    this.filteredBooks = books.filter(
      book => book.categories.filter(cat => cat.categoryId === this.route.snapshot.params['categoryId']));

   console.log(this.filteredBooks);
  });
  }                                                                                                                    It returns the unfiltered books, so updateList() method shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Yes. Your code is ok. But, It is risky since you do data transformation on UI component. from view of architecture this is bad. You should put it in **reducer**